# Extracting text after tag in Python's ElementTree

Tags: python, text, xml-parsing, elementtree

Here is a part of XML:

```
<item><img src="cat.jpg" /> Picture of a cat</item>
```

Extracting the  tag is easy. Just do:

```
et = xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring(our_xml_string)
img = et.find('img')
```

But how to get the text immediately after it (*Picture of a cat*)? Doing the following returns a blank string:

```
print et.text
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Elements have a `tail` attribute -- so instead of `element.text`, you're asking for `element.tail`.

```
>>> import lxml.etree
>>> root = lxml.etree.fromstring('''<root><foo>bar</foo>baz</root>''')
>>> root[0]
<Element foo at 0x145a3c0>
>>> root[0].tail
'baz'
```

Or, for your example:

```
>>> et = lxml.etree.fromstring('''<item><img src="cat.jpg" /> Picture of a cat</item>''')
>>> et.find('img').tail
' Picture of a cat'
```

This also works with plain ElementTree:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree
>>> xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring(
...   '''<item><img src="cat.jpg" /> Picture of a cat</item>'''
... ).find('img').tail
' Picture of a cat'
```

Comment: Brilliant. I tried using `.tail` before, but I was using it on my _el_ object. Did not realise I had to use it on *img*. Thank you for enlightening me!

Comment: @Neuron, ElementTree is a library name, not a code snippet. Its original formatting was deliberate. See [When should code formatting be used for non-code text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text) and [Should code formatting be used for package names?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369566/should-code-formatting-be-used-for-package-names) on [meta].

Comment: Thanks for the meta posts. though I am aware, that package names should not be code highlighted. I thought you were referencing the type ElementTree, not the package