# Getting and setting XML tail (text outside tags) with python elementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, tail

I have used the information in this link, however i can't get it work for file parsing:

[Extracting text after tag in Python's ElementTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673906/extracting-text-after-tag-in-pythons-elementtree)

The parsing works fine, as the attribute fetch works well. Just the tail fails.

I also then need to be able to adjust the 'tail' with my own text but I can't see a way of doing this with: xml.etree.ElementTree.set() as there is no way to adjust tail as an attribute?

I am unable to use the lxml library in this example :( so I am stuck with xml.elementree

```
#my file contains '<favourites><favourite src="cat.jpg" />Picture of a cat</favourites>'
import xml.etree.ElementTree
rootF = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse('/home/pi/bin/test/test_xml.xml')
for elements in rootF.iter('favourite'):    #iterate through each element
        print "src:", elements.attrib.get('src')
        print "tail:", elements.find('favourite').tail
```

Any help gratefully received!

Comment: This questions heading "(text outside tags)" helped me find the member responsible (tail), just by a simple google search. Thanks for explaining heading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`elements` in your code already points to `<favourite>`, so you don't actually need `.find('favourite').` part :

```
.....
print "tail:", elements.tail
.....
```

**[[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/ryRLv8)]**