# How do I iterate through ElementTree and delete all <mark> tags?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

So I have a large xml file with data I am parsing out. An example is below:

```
<statement>
<plist>
<p>Hello Stack Overflow.</p>
<p>This doesn't <mark type="NA" /> seem to work!</p>
</plist>
</statement>
```

The program I have developed only returns "Hello Stack Overflow. This doesn't"
In order to parse the rest of the line I would like to remove the mark tags at the before parsing. Using the root.findall('.//mark') function I was able to locate the marks but root.remove(marks) when looping through the returns of findall function doesn't work because the path from root to these tags is unknown. I also attempted to find all instances of p tags and search them for mark tags and then remove them using "p tag".remove("mark tag"), this did not fail but didn't seem to work either. Any suggestions?

This is not a dupliucate of anything that requires lxml import as this can have NO dependencies and must be solved using only Element Tree Functionality.

Comment: To remove an element, you obviously need to know the *parent* of the element.  Have you looked at the methods available on an `ElementTree` element?

Comment: Yeah, there is no direct way to access the parent node. But as I said before, all mark tags are located in the text enclosed by p tags. So by iterating through all p tags and checking if 'mark' is included, I could locate the parent node (the p tag) and use that to remove the mark tag. However, after I finish this and attempt to parse the text, the text still cuts off at the point where the mark tag was (or still is). So I'm at a bit of a loss.

Comment: There *is* a direct way to access the parent node.

Comment: How? All documentation I read seemed to specify you couldn't by design.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to remove an element in lxml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981840/how-to-remove-an-element-in-lxml)

Comment: See new edit please.

Comment: ElementTree parses text before the <mark/> into the 'text' attribute, and the text after it into the 'tail' attribute. When removing the mark tag you will have to append the 'tail' attribute content onto the 'text' attribute content.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @barny! One more quick question, when I try and print the tail I onyl get '\n             ' instead of the tail text. I'm sure I can dig around and figure this out but I figured I'd check and see if you knew a quick fix first

Comment: oops, the tail is attached to the mark - append mark.tail to 'text' of the p tag before deleting the mark tag. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673906/extracting-text-after-tag-in-pythons-elementtree

Comment: Yup, that did it. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ElementTree parses text before the <mark/> into the 'text' attribute of the containing p tag, and the text after it into the 'tail' attribute of the mark tag.

The solution is to find the p tags, look inside them for the mark tags, and before deleting the mark, appends its tail value to the text of the containing p.