# XML parse ignores text

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have the following issue, trying to get information from a bunch of xml files in python. I'm not doing anything special, eg:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse(r'C:\Documents\XMLfolder\file.xml').getroot()
info = root.find('foo').find('bar').find('info').text
```

This works with most of the info I have - but one section of the xml is in the following format:

```
<bar>
<info id="1"><label>1</label>SampleTextHere</info>
</bar>
```

The above code gives `None` - I can locate the `info` element and the `label` element, though. I just can't find the text. If I edit the file to remove `<label> 1 </label>` then the above code returns the text I need.

Is there something very basic that I don't know which would allow me to access the text without modifying all my xml files to remove the label? (It is relevant).

Thank you!

Comment: Very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/9673906/407651. "SampleTextHere" is the `tail` of the `<label>` element. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.tail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [[Python 3]: xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.**text**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.text) (**emphasis** is mine):

> These attributes can be used to hold additional data associated with the element. **Their values are usually strings but may be any application-specific object**. If the element is created from an XML file, the *text* attribute holds either the text between the element’s start tag and its first child or end tag, or `None`, and the *tail* attribute holds either the text between the element’s end tag and the next tag, or `None`.
>
> ...
>
> **To collect the inner text of an element, see [itertext()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.itertext)**, for example `"".join(element.itertext())`.

I created 3 files, based on your specification:

- *file0.xml*:

  ```xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <root>
    <foo>
      <bar>
        <info id="1">SampleTextHere 0</info>
      </bar>
    </foo>
  </root>
  ```
- *file1.xml*:

  ```xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <root>
    <foo>
      <bar>
        <info id="1"><label>LabelText</label>SampleTextHere 1</info>
      </bar>
    </foo>
  </root>
  ```
- *file2.xml*:

  ```xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <root>
    <foo>
      <bar>
        <info id="1"></info>
      </bar>
    </foo>
  </root>
  ```

and some sample code.

*code.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


def main():
    file_names = [
        "file0.xml",
        "file1.xml",
        "file2.xml",
    ]

    for file_name in file_names:
        root = ET.parse(file_name).getroot()
        info_node = root.find("foo").find("bar").find("info")
        text = info_node.text
        tail = info_node.tail
        iter_text = "".join(info_node.itertext())
        info_node_text = text or ""
        if not info_node_text:
            for info_node_text in info_node.itertext():
                pass
        print("\n{:s}\n      Text (for debugging purposes): [{:}]\n      Tail (for debugging purposes): [{:}]\n      Iter text (for debugging purposes): [{:s}]\n  Value: [{:s}]".format(
            file_name, text, tail, iter_text, info_node_text))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
```

The algorithm is straightforward: if the node doesn't have the *text* attribute set, iterate over its `itertext()` and pick the last value, as the *label* (or any other) sub node comes before the text.

**Output**:

> ```py
> (py_064_03.06.08_test0) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q054197111>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_064_03.06.08_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
> Python 3.6.8 (tags/v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 00:16:47) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
>
> file0.xml
>       Text (for debugging purposes): [SampleTextHere 0]
>       Tail (for debugging purposes): [
>     ]
>       Iter text (for debugging purposes): [SampleTextHere 0]
>   Value: [SampleTextHere 0]
>
> file1.xml
>       Text (for debugging purposes): [None]
>       Tail (for debugging purposes): [
>     ]
>       Iter text (for debugging purposes): [LabelTextSampleTextHere 1]
>   Value: [SampleTextHere 1]
>
> file2.xml
>       Text (for debugging purposes): [None]
>       Tail (for debugging purposes): [
>     ]
>       Iter text (for debugging purposes): []
>   Value: []
> ```